# What's meaning of a derivative to its original funciton?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have trouble of finding the relationship of a function's derivative with its original function.

Suppose there is a function: $$s = f(x)=16x^2 + 2$$

So its derivative is $$s'=f'(x)=32x$$

Here's the output of function:
$$f(1) = 16 \times(1^2)+2=18$$
$$f(3) = 16 \times(3^2)+2=146$$
$$f(4) = 16 \times(4^2)+2=258$$

But according to the formula:$$s + \Delta s = f(x +\Delta x) $$

$$s(3)+s(1)\neq f(3+1)$$

So my questions are:

1) If derivative is the rate of original function, how does it apply in this case?

2) In the last inequation, what's wrong with it?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: The derivative is the rate of change in that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) +  f'(x)( \Delta x) + r(x,\Delta x)$, where $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{r(x,\Delta x)}{\Delta x} = 0$. Intuitively, the tangent line is very close to the realization, and the error $r(x,\Delta x)$ between the approximation and the realization tends to 0 faster than linear time.

Comment: @Nitin But the error $$r(x,Δx)$$in that case has almost half large of realization, how can this apply in physics?

Comment: I am confused by your last equation. You have written $s(3) + s(1) \neq f(3 + 1)$, but you *defined* $s = f$. You equation won't hold unless $f$ is linear no matter what.

Comment: Also, the linear approximation is only good for extremely small values of $\Delta x$. You can use Taylor polynomials and LaGrangian error bounds to find the largest $\Delta x$ that will work so that the linear approximation does not exceed some predetermined error. The more information (i.e. higher order derivatives) we know, the better we can tighten this bound.

Comment: $\Delta s$ is not equal to $s(\Delta x)$. Rather, $\Delta s = s(x+\Delta x)-s(x)$. In your case, then, $\Delta s \neq s(1)$, rather $\Delta s = s(4)-s(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the rate of change of the function $f$ at any given time $x$. In fact Newton created it precisely to measure that.

Now rate of change changes to the original function, NOT the derivative, and since the rate of change is not constant, so we can only get an approximate. Hence the formula is in fact

$$f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x \text{   (Linerization)}$$

that is the value of the function after $\Delta x$ seconds will be the value of the function at $x$ seconds plus the changes done in $\Delta x$ seconds, with the error get bigger with bigger $\Delta x$.

(You can think of your old grade 10 or 11 slope formula. For linear functions 
$f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + m \Delta x$ where $m$ is the slope aka derivative. Or if you are more familiar with the slope intercept formula, a linear function is 
$f(\Delta x) = m \Delta x + b$ where $b = f(0)$ the $y$-intercept. Hence the name linearization, we estimate the function with a linear one.)

For your example, so near $x = 3, $ the rate of change is $f'(3) = 32 \cdot 3 = 96$. $\Delta x = 1$

So

$$f(x + \Delta x) = f(4) = 258$$

$$f(x) + f'(x) \Delta(x) = 146 + 96 \cdot 1 = 242$$

I'd call that pretty damn close, and look at your original function, it's $x^2$, and the rate of change is $+32 x$, meaning the function increases speeds up. Hence our estimate provided a lower one.

So long sentences short, either your formula is wrong, or you miss understood $\Delta s$, which is actually suppose to be $s'\cdot \delta x$. Because $\delta s = f(\delta x)$ has nothing to do with rate of change.

Hope it helps.